# How to run test cases with the spring-boot framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I downloaded and successfully ran this project:

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mongodb

I noticed it has some test cases on the file:

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mongodb/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/CustomerRepositoryTests.java

To run the main application from the command line, I do:

```
$ ./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Now, I would like to know what command do I need to execute in order to run the test cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run this command to run your tests.

> mvn test

https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ can give you more information about testing.